# powerShell: Start-Process -Wait sometimes does not return although child process exitted and cannot be found in taksmanager anymore

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, start-process

I am currently trying to write a short PowerShell script which is supposed to start a custom commandline executable, and wait for the process to finish, and continue execution when the process terminated.

So basically my code looks very simple, like this:

```
Start-Process "myCmdLineApp.exe" -Wait
Write-Host "Process finished, exitting..."
```

My observation is that in 99% of all cases, this works flawlessly. But in rare conditions, I observe that myCmdLineApp.exe finished, but the PowerShell script is still waiting for the process. I checked in taskmanager of course, but myCmdLineApp.exe is definitely not running anymore, but my script doesn't continue.

I am now wondering what I might examine further, or what might cause this strange behaviour. Thank you for any ideas or comments on that topic!

Comment: Your `myCmdLineApp.exe` might open child processes or file handles remaining open ... ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, how can I check this? Do child processes really matter as long as the myCmdLineApp.exe exits and is destroyed? What exactly does Start-Process Wait for when the wait parameter is supplied? In my understanding it should be sufficient for the exe to terminate, or what else needs to be assured, and how can it be checked?

Comment: If that happens occasionally / randomly and you cannot reproduce it on purpose it may be hard to figure out where it comes from. You may try the Sysinternals tools like "Process Explorer" which is able to show a processes hierarchy. And file handles can be checked with "handle.exe".

Comment: Did you check the event viewer for errors?

Comment: sysinternals process monitor filter "operation contains process"

Comment: Waiting for a whole process tree can be a useful feature in other cases.